# Need help replacing & with &amp;

Tags: php, replace, html-entities

I have no idea why I'm not able replace `&` with `&amp;`

This is my string: `/Designers/batlak&selvig.jpg`.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
$image = preg_replace("#(&(?!amp;))#U",'&amp;',$brand['image']);
$image = str_replace('&','&amp;',$brand['image']);
$image = htmlspecialchars($brand['image']);
$image = mysql_real_escape_string($brand['image']);
$image = urlencode($brand['image']); // This works, but image will not show
$image = rawurlencode($brand['image']);  // This works, but image will not show
```

Any suggestions?

**update**

Yes, it's a part of an image url used by the `<img>` tag.
`urlencode` does not work - the image tag does not understand the format.

This is the error I get at W3C Validator:

```
Validation Output: 1 Error 
Line 84, Column 104: & did not start a character reference. 
(& probably should have been escaped as &amp;.)
```

**UPDATE 2**

This is how I'm testing it:

```
<?php 
   $image = str_replace('&','&amp;',$brand['image']); 
   echo $image; 
?>
```

**Output:**
`/Designers/batlak&selvig.jpg`

I've also tested replacing `$brand['image']` with `/Designers/batlak&selvig.jpg`

Comment: Where do you want to use that string value?

Comment: Looks like a URL? If so, have a look at `urlencode()`

Comment: Strange, $image = htmlspecialchars($brand['image']); works for me.

Comment: Why &amp;? Are you trying to have the page render that image or pass it as a URL argument?

Comment: @Evan: It's not passign the W3C validator having & in the img url

Comment: Tried `rawurlencode` - http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php?

Comment: $Phil: I just tried. Using `rawurlencode` or `urlencode` does endeed repalce `&` with `%26`, but then the image will not show.

Comment: For use in HTML, you really should be using `htmlspecialchars`, eg `echo htmlspecialchars($brand['image']);`

Comment: @Phil: Tested that. Nothing happends.

Answer (score 4):

Works for me:

```
echo str_replace('&', '&amp;', '/Designers/batlak&selvig.jpg');

// output:
Designers/batlak&amp;selvig.jpg
```

Perhaps you are throwing this into an href or src where it is escaped in the browser status/location bar. If you look in the source code, it will be properly escaped.

Comment: I'm using Firebug and I still see the lonely `&`.

Comment: Your test code from Update 2 should be something like: `$image = str_replace('&','&amp;',$brand['image']); echo $image;` You're not assigning the output of str_replace to anything.

Comment: Sorry, just a typo here at SO.

Answer (score 1):

For a URL:

```
$image = urlencode($brand['image'])
```

For your question:

```
preg_replace('/&(?![A-Za-z0-9#]{1,7};)/','&amp;',$brand['image']);
```

That replaces all `'&'` without replacing any existing `'&amp;'` characters.

Comment: it's kind of tricky to test, because the browser changes the special char, but you can send the "text/plain" header for testing:
`header('Content-Type:text/plain');`

Answer (score 1):

Firebug does "auto-hide" HTML entities.

So please run and paste the raw (View Source, Copy, Paste) result:

```
var_dump($brand['image']);
var_dump(urlencode($brand['image']));
var_dump(htmlspecialchars($brand['image']));
```

My guess would be:

```
$image = htmlspecialchars(urlencode($brand['image']));
```

The problem is appearantly that you have an ampersand in your filename which is... tricky ;)

Comment: `var_dump` only gives me String(32) and the file name / link. I also tried this without result: `$image = urlencode($brand['image']); echo htmlspecialchars($image);`

Comment: Could you please paste the result from the var_dump?